# Why does Witten say that his work only makes sense if magnetic monopoles exist?

Tags: magnetic-monopoles

Witten emphasises  (in the Q&A session after his [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuJY14BYac4) on introductory knot theory) that he works on theories which admit magnetic monopoles.

But how would the theories break down if magnetic monopoles do not exist? What are the theories that he eludes to?

$\mathsf{NOTE}$: I am well aware that there is a related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/why-do-physicists-believe-that-there-exist-magnetic-monopoles) which asks why contemporary physicists believe in the existence of monopoles, but it isn't similar.

Comment: One of his indication is in fact towards the Seiberg-Witten theory. Where the The solutions of the Seiberg–Witten equations are called monopoles.

Comment: I think you already answered your question: He *works on theories which admit magnetic monopoles*. Therefore, those theories describe a world in which magnetic monopoles exist. I'm not sure what there is to elaborate.

Comment: The theories he's alluding to are string theory and Yang-Mills-Higgs theories with more symmetry than the Standard Model, such as grand unified theories.