# Does magnetic monopoles really exist?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-monopoles

I have found out some research going at CERN (LHC) . Is it true that monopoles behave like electrons or protons? and thus prove quantization of charge?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4784/2451 and links therein.

Comment: They haven’t been found, and if they were found they wouldn’t behave like electrons or protons.