# Are the Maxwell's equations enough to derive the law of Coulomb?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, maxwell-equations, coulombs-law

Are the 8 Maxwell's equations enough to derive the formula for the electromagnetic field created by a stationary point charge, which is the same as the [law of Coulomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) 
$$  F~=~k_e \frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}~?  $$
If I am not mistaken, due to the fact that Maxwell's equations are differential equations, their general solution must contain arbitrary constants. Aren't some boundary conditions and initial conditions needed to have a unique solution. How is it possible to say without these conditions, that a stationary point charge does not generate magnetic field, and the electric scalar potential is equal to

$$\Phi(\mathbf{r})=\frac{e}{r}.$$

If the conditions are needed, what kind of conditions are they for the situation described above (the field of stationary point charge)?

Comment: For essentially the opposite question(v3), see [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3618/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Yes, I have already read this post, but my question is quite different.

Comment: Wouldn't it be trivial to apply the divergence theorem to Gauss' law to get it in its integral form. From here it seems easy enough to use the usual tricks to find the electric field of a point charge, and then multiply by some charge to get your force. Surely this is Coulomb's force law?

Comment: Why 8 Maxwell's equations and not 4? I am missing something?

Comment: @DanilH: I meant 8 scalar equations. From the 4 Maxwell's equations two are vector equations.

Comment: @Daniel Blay: I guess when you say usual tricks you mean taking a spherical surface around the point charge. The problem for me is that how do we know that the magnitude of the electric field from a point charge is spherically-symmetric. Besides how can we derive that there is no magnetic field (if it is possible to derive from Maxwell's equations)? :)

Comment: Spherical symmetry is not incorporated in Maxwell's equation. To go from Gauss' law to Coulomb's law for point-like particles which produces a spherical symmetric electric field in the space this assumption has to be made. In addition, Maxwell's equations do not tell you that there is no magnetic field, they just tell you that there are no magnetic monopoles (Gauss' law again). Electric and magnetic fields are two sides of the same field: electromagnetic field.

Answer (score 19):

The short answer is yes, and in fact you only need one single Maxwell equation, Gauss's law, together with the Lorentz force, to get Coulomb's law.

More specifically, you need Gauss's law in its *integral* form, which is equivalent to the differential form for well-behaved fields because of [Gauss's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem). Thus, you use the law
$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=\rho/\epsilon_0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \oint_S\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{a}=Q/\epsilon_0,
$$
where $Q$ is the total charge enclosed by the (arbitrary) surface $S$.

To derive Coulomb's law, consider the electric field of a single point particle, with nothing else in the universe. Because of isotropy (which must be added as an additional postulate), the electric field at a sphere of radius $r$ centred on the charge must be radial and with the same magnitude throughout. That means the integral is trivial and the electric field must be
$$\mathbf{E}=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}.$$

Coupled with Lorentz's force law at zero velocity for the test particle (since Coulomb's law only holds in electrostatics) this yields Coulomb's law.

It is not obvious that this highly symmetric situation can give the general electrostatic force for multiple particles. This follows from the superposition principle, which is very much at the heart of classical electrodynamics, and which can be obtained from the linearity of Maxwell's equations. This gives you the field for a single source; add the fields for all the individual sources and you'll get the field for the collection of sources.

Answer (score 12):

The exact derivation goes as follows. You start from Gauss' Law, integrate on both sides over some volume V:

$$
\stackrel{\tiny div}{\vec{\nabla}}\cdot\vec{\mathbf{E}}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\rho \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\Big/\iiint\limits_V\,d^3\vec{r}
$$
Then switch to integration over a closed surface, and also note that total charge inside this volume is Q:
$$
\iiint\limits_V\stackrel{\tiny div}{\vec{\nabla}}\cdot\vec{\mathbf{E}}\,\,d^3\vec{r}=\oint\vec{\mathbf{E}}\cdot d\vec\sigma=\iiint\limits_V\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\rho\,\,d^3\vec{r}=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}
$$
Now you need to note that the volume of integration is quite arbitrary and so is the surface, so we will use a sphere. You can describe the integral over a sphere using:
$$
\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}=\oint\vec{\mathbf{E}}\cdot d\vec\sigma=\int\limits_{\phi=0}^{\phi=2\pi}\int\limits_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi}\mathbf{E}\hat{\vec{n}}\cdot\hat{\vec{n}}\,R\,d\phi\,R\,d\theta=4\pi R^2\mathbf{E}\,\,\,\,\,\,\Big/\frac{1}{4\pi R^2}
$$
And so you obtain:
$$
\mathbf{E}=\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 R^2}
$$
It should be:
$$\vec{\mathbf{E}}=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$$
But I lost the normal vector along the way (I hope that someone can correct this and edit this post).

Now you use the Lorentz Force law (where $\vec{\mathbf{B}}=\vec 0$):
$$
\vec{\mathbf{F}}_{lor}=q \vec{\mathbf{E}}+q \vec{\mathbf{V}}\times\vec{\mathbf{B}}=\frac{q\,Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}
$$
And so you obtain the Coulomb force law.

Comment: No you didn't lost the unit vector. You calculated the charge, which is not a vector. It's a geometric argument(already given in the previous answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/44423/16689 : *the electric field at a sphere of radius r centred on the charge must be radial and with the same magnitude throughout*) that allow you to recover the vector form of the electric field.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping for a more strict (mathematically speaking) method of recovering the unit vector. It is true that charge is not a vector, so it is impossible to obtain a unit vector in this calculation. But simply "adding" (writing) it after derivation is complete is not what I prefer. Maybe we can do it strictly mathematically if we use the $\hat{\vec{z}}$ axis which currently is used only to define the $\theta$ angle inside the integral.

Answer (score 10):

If you are asking about the Coloumb's law for the electric **fields**, **yes**, which you can see others' answers.

If you are asking about the Coloumb's law for the electric **force**,

$$\text{NO!}$$

Maxwell equations do NOT tell you about how the force acting on the charges $q$ or currents $\vec{J}$.

Simply speaking, to FULLY understand classical E&M (i.e. one can determine the physics from a initial value problem to determine all its consequences - **physics** is all about to determine/predict the future), you need BOTH:

**(1) Maxwell's equations**

**(2) Lorentz force law (Newtonian mechanics, E&M equivalence of Newtonian gravitation force.)**

Punch line I: **(1) and (2) are absolute different things.**

---

> Lagrangian and variational principle E.O.M. viewpoint

However, if you start from a Lagrangian viewpoint, writing down the action:
$$
S=\int  (-\frac{1}{2} |f|^2 + A \wedge *J)=\int d^3xdt (-\frac{1}{4} f_{\mu\nu} f^{\mu\nu} + A_\mu J^\mu)
$$
with the 2-form field strength $f_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$ gives you E and M fields, you can determine **Maxwell's equation** from the equations of motions(E.O.M.) by doing the variation principle on the 1=form gauge field $A$. The source is a 1-form current $J=(\rho,\vec{J})$.

> **Maxwell's equations: E.O.M. respect to varying 1-form gauge field $A$**

You obtain **Maxwell equations** by varying $A$:
$$
d*F=J \;\;\;\text{-Gauss law for electricity, Maxwell-Ampere's law}
$$
and
$$
dF=d^2A=0 \;\;\;\text{-Gauss's law for magnetism, Maxwell–Faraday equation}
$$

How about the Lorentz force law? You can do variation respect to the spatial coordinate $x^\mu=(t,x)$, and **you need to specify which massive particle with mass $m$** experiencing the force $F$, which is $F=m \ddot{\vec{x}}$ by Newtonian mechanics. To specify massive particle in the Lagrangian/action, you just need to add its kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2}m \dot{\vec{x}}^2$.

> **Lorentz force law: E.O.M. respect to varying spacetime coordinates $x^\mu=(t,x)$**

$$
S=\int d^3xdt (-\frac{1}{4} f_{\mu\nu} f^{\mu\nu} + A_\mu \wedge J^\mu+\frac{1}{2}m \dot{\vec{x}}^2) \to \int d^3xdt (+ q\Phi - q \dot{\vec{x}} \cdot \vec{A}+\frac{1}{2}m \dot{\vec{x}}^2)
$$

you will derive Lorentz force law
$$
m \ddot{\vec{x}}=q\vec{E}+q \dot{\vec{x}} \times \vec{B}
$$

Punch line II: The action and Variational principles are very powerful to **unite (1) Maxwell's equations and (2) Lorentz force law, in the same framework.**

Comment: The above sketch of derivation of force on point particles appears in good books, but has a fundamental flaw for point particles. For such particles, the interaction field term has no value, since the field is singular at the particle, and the pure field term is infinite, which invalidates any formal differentiation. The result, although it seems correct, is wrong: as vector potential, the total electric and magnetic fields are not defined at the place of the particle $\vec{x}$.

Comment: @  Ján Lalinský, thanks but you miss my point. The field is **NOT** from the singular-size point particle, but **from the** **external** source surrounding it. Such as external current, electric planes, etc. The derivation is carried out the external EM effects on the point particle.

Comment: So your comment is actually NOT to my point.

Comment: In the first part of your derivation, you talk about deriving Maxwell equations, so there $f_{\mu\nu}, A_\mu$ are total fields produced by prescribed sources. In the second part after "How about the Lorentz force law? ", if by $f_{\mu\nu}, A_\mu$ you refer to external fields, the derivation is correct, but please consider making this clear in your text: due to the first part and even without it, when most people see these symbols, they assume they refer to the total field.

Answer (score 1):

Given the Gauss law AND the Lorentz force, yes it's possible to derive Coulomb's law as it already been answered. So I think the question is if it's possible to derive it given ONLY the four Maxwell equations (and *not* the Lorentz force). The answer is still yes since the Lorentz force is equivalent to the Faraday law and it can be derive from it. The relation between Faraday law and Lorentz force is not trivial in 3D since the Faraday paradox arises (check wiki). On the other hand when electromagnetism is expressed in the covariant formulation no such paradox exists.

Comment: Lorentz force formula does not follow from Maxwell's equations, nor from the Faraday law $\nabla \times \mathbf E = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}$, which is part of Maxwell's equations.