# When is Gauss' law not applicable?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, maxwell-equations, gauss-law

Does Gauss law hold in all cases, including the ones where charges are moving at speeds comparable to light?

What I think: Gauss law does not hold true when charges are moving at very high speeds. For example, assume a sphere and a charge kept midway between the center and a point on the sphere. If the charge moves towards A, then, the increase in electric field is communicated to the region near A quicker than the decrease in the field near the diametrically opposite end of A is communicated, so the flux should be more than expected at that time. Obviously, this is just a thought and may be wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gauss's Law with Moving Charges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63547/)

Comment: The post marked as a duplicate addresses the same question but the answer there is incomplete as it  does not account for time delay, as explicitly requested by the OP.

Answer (score 7):

Gauss’ Law is the integral form of one of Maxwell’s equations,

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf E=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}.$$

All of Maxwell’s equations are consistent with Special Relativity; they don’t change their form under Lorentz transformations.

Therefore Gauss’ Law applies in all inertial reference frames, including ones where charged particles are moving at speeds near $c$.

Comment: The question is if the integral form of Gauss's law is covariant.

Comment: The integral forms of Maxwell’s equations are mathematically equivalent to the differential forms, so it is.