# Maxwell-like equations from Newton's law of universal gravitation and special relativity

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, relativity, maxwell-equations

It is known that [Maxwell's equations can be derived from Coulomb's Law and Special Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/can-maxwells-equations-be-derived-from-coulombs-law-and-special-relativity). Since Coulomb's Law is so similar to Newton's law of universal gravitation, is it also possible to derive Maxwell-like equations from Newton's law of universal gravitation and special relativity?

I suspect the answer is no, because I've never seen it done and I am guessing that the fact that charge can be positive or negative while mass can only be positive has something to do with why not.

Comment: I think some of the components of the stress-energy tensor becomes newtons law of gravitation (in the potential form) in some kind of limit. If I remember correct it is the components with the time coordinate (0). Since Maxwells equations do not have mass in them as far as I remember it seems unlikely.

Comment: Hint: Look up [gravitoelectromagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism).

Comment: It has been tried, and you get "similar" equations to Maxwell's. One of the problems is that   it does not bend light. Another is negative energy waves, although this last one I am not sure why is a problem (page 81 of MTW).

Comment: This one does show the steps and some references, although I am not sure if it is correct.http://vixra.org/abs/1701.0533