# Cause of Magnetic Fields

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, magnetic-fields, speed-of-light

I read this on Quora in this [question](https://www.quora.com/How-are-the-electric-field-and-the-magnetic-field-related-by-the-special-theory-of-relativity) in an answer by Peter Webb.

> The magnetic forces are not real forces, they are virtual forces.
>   They essentially derive from the time lag it takes an electric field
>   to propagate, and that depends on the frame in which you take your
>   measurement

What is exactly meant by 'the time lag it takes an electric field to propagate'?

Comment: The force of a magnet I have feels very real. I think your question is moot unless you strictly define real and virtual.

Answer (score 4):

The distinction between "real" and "virtual" forces that seems to be made here is non-standard. Both electric and magnetic fields depend on the frame of reference, and there is no evident meaning to calling one real and the other virtual.

That said, what this statement is likely trying to get at is the very correct notion that electromagnetism can be seen entirely as "just" electrostatics in the form of Coulomb's law together with the theory of special relativity, see [this question and its answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3618/50583). Since relativity inherently comes with limiting the speed of propagation to the speed light, one *might* phrase that as "essentially[...] the time lag it takes an electric field to propagate", but once again, that is a non-standard viewpoint.